# Avoiding "Missed Schedule" errors when inserting future posts

Tags: posts, cron

I'm inserting future posts as you'd expect using a `post_status` of `future` and a future `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`.

The dates look fine in WordPress, but these posts appear with the "Missed Schedule" warning. They haven't missed schedule yet because they're future posts.

My guess is that it's because when inserting these future posts I'm not adding a cron event. Is this hunch correct and if so, do I simply schedule an event after the publish time? If not, what can I do to avoid  "Missed Schedule" errors when inserting future posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missed schedule warning comes form those lines: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f884d7973b052c3efe0901bb136b9898ece8aa39/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L998,L999

It should be independent on any cron event, as the warning is being displayed only in case the current UTC time - post_date_gmt > 0 - there is no other condition (except for post having the `future` status).

In order to debug the issue, check what value is saved in the database in the `post_date_gmt` column of the post object with the false-positive warning. The value returned from PHP's `time()` should always be UTC so I don't expect any issues there.

In case the post has correct GMT time, check whether some of installed plugins is not filtering the `get_post_time` filter used in [get_post_time](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_time/) function used here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f884d7973b052c3efe0901bb136b9898ece8aa39/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L984,L986

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was using `get_gmt_from_date()` to generate a GMT date given a localized time, when it does the reverse. So my `post_date` appeared fine but the `post_date_gmt` was generating this warning, showing me the underlying post date is not OK. Your pointers to core (aside from giving me flashbacks to previous questions) got me pointed at the problem. Thank you David!